# Why is io.sockets.in not working with my code?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Client Side script

```
var socket = io.connect();
var room = "abc123";

socket.on('connect', function() {

socket.emit('room', room);
});

socket.on('message', function(data) {
 console.log('Incoming message:', data);
});
```

Server side script

```
io = socketio.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
 socket.on('room', function(room) {
    socket.join(room);
});
});
room = "abc123";
io.sockets.in(room).emit('message', 'what is going on, party 
people?');
```

I am trying to send message to abc123 but io.sockets is not working.

Comment: What are you hosting socketio with? express or http server?

Comment: change `io = socketio.listen(server); ` to `io = socketio.listen(port);` and check if it is working or not